# justpy app don't work on AWS Lightsail; no error but also no page visible

Tags: hosting, amazon-lightsail, justpy

A python file with this code:

```
import justpy as jp

def hello_world():
  wp = jp.WebPage()
  jp.Hello(a=wp)
  return wp

jp.justpy(hello_world)
```

A justpy.env file with this parameters:

```
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8000
```

A Lightsail Ubuntu VM with static URL runs the file with output on console:

```
ubuntu@ip-xy:~$ python3 run.py
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/justpy
Module directory: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/justpy, Application dire
ctory: /home/ubuntu
JustPy ready to go on http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

[Page not shown. What is missing?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSxGP.png)

What is missing? I suffer with this.

Comment: Did you open a browser pointing with url at port 8000 of the ubuntu machine such as http://localhost:8080?